# ISA wrong translation of the schema URL included in WSDL

Tags: url, isa-server, url-routing

I have a WSDL behind ISA server. The WSDL includes a schema
`<xsd:include schemaLocation="myschema.xsd"/>`

However, when accessed through ISA, some implicit mapping changes the server name to the name of the application "TEST" as shown in the xsd:include line below

`<xsd:include schemaLocation="http://TEST:8345/myservice?xsd=myschema.xsd"/>`

The WSDL is accessible using the URL - 
`https://services.mycompany.com/myservice?wsdl`

The schema is accessible using the URL -
`https://services.mycompany.com/myservice?xsd=myschema.xsd`

The problem is that the translated URL for schema in the WSDL is incorrect. It needs to be

`<xsd:include schemaLocation="https://services.mycompany.com/myservice?xsd=myschema.xsd"/>`

instead of

`<xsd:include schemaLocation="http://TEST:8345/myservice?xsd=myschema.xsd"/>`

Does ISA guy need to set some ISA rules (for replacing the URL in WSDL) for this? What rule does he need to create/change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude XML's from being translated.  There's a couple ways to do this but this is how I got mine to work.
Go to Firewall Policy > Toolbox > Content Types > HTML Documents > Content Types.  Select text/xml from the available types list and hit Add.  Apply your changes and try again.